# Sorting file versions by leading amount of digits

Tags: powershell

I created a script to create a report to list all files that are not up to date. I would like to order these files by those that start with 2018. first. Outside of that I have no preference.

```
dir *.exe | %{ $_.VersionInfo } | Where-Object {$_.FileVersion -NotMatch "^2018.1"} | Sort-Object FileVersion -Descending > V:\file.path\binFileVersion.txt
```

My current output:

```
4.0.30319.01
3.10.0.0
2018.0.0.0
2018.0.0.0
2018.0.0.0
2018.0.0.0
2.5.3.5
15, 0, 3, 0
1.0.0.0
```

Desired output:

```
2018.0.0.0
2018.0.0.0
2018.0.0.0
2018.0.0.0
Everything else
Everything else
```

I've been tinkering around but haven't really found a solution. I saw another post about pad left but that didn't really do the intended action.

Thanks!

Someone posted an answer that works but was deleted before I could approve it.

```
$Match,$NotMatch = (dir *.exe | %{ $_.VersionInfo } | Where-Object {$_.FileVersion -NotMatch "^2018.1"} | Sort-Object FileVersion -Descending).Where({$_.FileVersion -like '2018*'},'Split') 
@($Match,$NotMatch)
```

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `.Where()` method with the split overload, to split it into two collections on whether it matches `2018*`. Then return the matched collection first.

```
$Match,$NotMatch = (dir *.exe | %{ $_.VersionInfo } | Where-Object {$_.FileVersion -NotMatch "^2018.1"} | Sort-Object FileVersion -Descending).Where({$_.FileVersion -like '2018*'},'Split')
@($Match,$NotMatch)
```

Note: Requires PowerShell 4+

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex, try this:

```
dir *.exe | %{ $_.VersionInfo } | Where-Object {$_.FileVersion -NotMatch "^2018.1"} | 
Sort-Object {[regex]::Match($_,'2018')} -Descending
```